# Sharepoint PublishingWebControls

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know the PublishingWebControls for a drop down

I have looked on msdn but nothing really stands out

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are trying to do, why not use [asp:DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)?